# A memory leak occurs at the part of the ArrayList. Can I ignore it using SoftReference?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am stressed because of the current memory leak problem.
I always memory leak check use `Allocation Tracking`.

Most of my apps when I use ArrayList part are memory leak.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PYID.png)

occur Memory leak source

```
private  ArrayList<SoftReference<OutputInputPair>> pairs = new ArrayList<SoftReference<OutputInputPair>>();

//record start...
@Override
public void process() {
    //get record camera preview file into queue
    for (SoftReference<OutputInputPair> pair : pairs ) {
         OutputInputPair actualPair = pair.get();
         actualPair.output.fillCommandQueues();
         actualPair.input.fillCommandQueues();
    } 

    //when record stop. stopped = true
    while (!stopped) { //recording...
        for (SoftReference<OutputInputPair> pair : pairs) {
             recording(pair);
        }
    }
 }
```

and

```
while(!stopped) {
     for (SoftReference<OutputInputPair> pair : pairs) {
          recording(pair);
     }
}
```

Until recording is stopped, `recording ()` is executed indefinitely.

in this part, Since the memory rick is the largest.

I as a temporary measure, use `SoftReference`

ah, when record stop, There is not occur  memory rick in that part.
only when record start, occur memory leak
Generally, when I use `SoftReference`, app not died. and not occur `OutOfMemory`.

but I know Even though you use SoftReference, the Allocation Tracking tool knows that a memory leak occurs.

So I basically want to fix a memory leak for this part.

How to fix this problem?

thanks.

Comment: Really, using SoftReference is never a *fix* for a memory leak. In this case, don't you want to keep recording on all `OutputInputPair`s? You don't just want to stop recording on one because you ran low on memory, right? And you would have a limited, known, amount of them so you can set your memory up front to the right size.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt  I want if memory is insufficient, Stop recording for a while, restart recording..   roundly, Is not it the most obvious way?

Comment: sorry but, I don't understand `And you would have a limited, know, amount of them so you can set your memory up front to the right size` ..

Comment: perhaps, If best way your app is running out of memory, stop recording and restart again for a while, then How to stop recording when memory is low?

Comment: Your problem is not clear enough. How would you recreate your OutputInputPair object later to restart recording if it was garbage collected?